# Counting multiple value ocurrences on multiple columns in a single query

Tags: mysql

I have a search section for looking up products which has a navigation bar for filtering purposes that shows the total results of each product feature. For example:

TOTAL RESULTS 60

- New (32)
- Used (28)

---

- Particular (10)
- Company (50)

---

In mysql I have the following queries (one per feature)

**Type**

```
    SELECT  a.id_type, whois.name as whoisName, COUNT(a.id_type) as  countWhois 

        FROM (published a
            INNER JOIN types whois ON whois.id = a.id_type)

        GROUP BY id_type

     +---------+------------+------------+
     | id_type | whoisName  | countWhois |
     +---------+------------+------------+
     |       0 | Company    |         50 |
     |       1 | Particular |         10 |
     +---------+------------+------------+
```

---

**Condition**

```
      SELECT  a.id_condition, cond.name as condName, COUNT(a.id_condition) as countCondition

        FROM (published a
                INNER JOIN conditions cond ON cond.id = a.id_condition)

        GROUP BY id_condition

     +--------------+---------------+----------------+
     | id_condition | conditionName | countCondition |
     +--------------+---------------+----------------+
     |            0 | New           |             32 |
     |            1 | Used          |             28 |
     +--------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I want to summarize the two queries in a single one but can´t figure out how. I was thinking something like this:

```
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| id_type | whoisName  | countWhois | id_condition | conditionName | countCondition |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| 0       | Company    | 50         | NULL         | NULL          | NULL           |
| 1       | Particular | 10         | NULL         | NULL          | NULL           |
| NULL    | NULL       | NULL       | 0            | New           | 32             |
| NULL    | NULL       | NULL       | 1            | Used          | 28             |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Is this possible?
Thanks and sorry if my English is bad, it's not my native language.

Comment: You need to provide us with a join column to connect the two tables.  The only option I see right now would be to do a `CROSS JOIN` (blind cross product), but this is not what you want either.

Comment: Union looks like a more credible candidate to me